# Restore an earlier document version -- Cannot see "my last edits" button for documents

Tags: restore, versioning

My environment is Sharepoint 2013 Standard.  On a test document library I have versioning turned off. According to this article, I should be able to restore my modified document back to previous version:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-document-versions-in-skydrive-pro-HA103158256.aspx

I just follow the instruction but I just cannot see the button "my last edits" or "UNDO CHANGES" anywhere. I am not sure what went wrong ...

Thanks for any input.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

the catch is:

This feature is available only if Document Versioning is turned off in OneDrive for Business. Additionally, **this feature applies only to documents you’ve shared with others**. It does not apply to documents other people have shared with you.

is it your document or others?

Also did you see ellspss(...)

Comment: I think so. I am testing by login as "Mark" and edit the file at "Skydrive Pro" (now is called OneDrive for business) "Shared with everyone" folder. Also I can see "...". Click on it shows a list with "View Properties, Edit Properties, Check Out, Compliance Details ... blah" but no "my last edit"